# ./abc.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: c++, c, linux, executable

I have a Linux Virtual Machine . There are some information.

`uname -a`: 
  `Linux 05d57a817610 4.4.0-131-generic #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`cat /proc/version`:  `Linux version 4.4.0-131-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-015) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ) #157-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 12 15:51:36 UTC 2018`

`cat /etc/issue`:  `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS \n \l`

```
/*abc.c*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I used the command `gcc abc.c -o abc.o` , then I got a file: `abc.o` . It was executable.

When I used the command: `gcc abc.c -c` , it produced a file `abc.o` . Then I tried to use the command: `./abc.o` , but it showed that `bash: ./abc.o: Permission denied`. With that , I used the command `chmod +x abc.o` , then I used the command `./abc.o` , it showed that `./abc.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.
I have been troubled by this problem for a long time, I didn't know why. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.Sorry for my poor English.

There are some information you may want to know when you solve the problem.

`file abc.o` : `abc.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

`uname -m` : `x86_64`

If you want to know any information, please leave a message in the comment. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to execute an object file? This cannot work, you have to link these to an executable binary first.

Comment: I don't think the .o file is your executeable. I don't know if things are different on Linux so im not posting this as an answer. But on Windows .o files are the object files that get linked to your final executable. You can't run those.

Comment: `gcc abc.c -o abc` does both, compiling and linking, so this is appropriate when having only one source file. `gcc abc.c -c` only does the first step, compiling the source file into an object file. You would do that, if you have several sourcefiles; compile each of these and then link them together in a last step: `gcc abc.o ... -o abc` to get your executable.

Comment: You probably have an `abc.exe` that windows picks up and executes. When you type `abc`, Windows automatically looks for an `abc.exe` to execute. This is probably causing you some confusion.

Answer (score 6):

`gcc -c` produces an object file, *not* an executable file. To create an executable file, you need to link the object file:

```
gcc abc.c -c
gcc abc.o -o abc
```

As a short-cut, you can compile a source file into a temporary object file *and* link that object file into an executable with a single command as well:

```
gcc abc.c -o abc
```

`gcc` is used for both compiling and linking (it's a front-end tool that invokes the compiler or the linker as needed.)

Comment: I use the command `gcc abc.c -o abc.o` ，`abc.o` was executable. But `-c` cannot, they have the same suffix `.o` , are they different?

Comment: @guapi On Windows, `gcc abc.c -o abc.o` will produce `abc.o.exe`. When you type `abc.o`, Windows executes `abc.o.exe`. And as I mentioned in the answer, `-c` produces *object files*, not executable files.

Comment: It's on Linux , not Windows. I know what you mean. command `gcc abc.c -o abc.o` and `gcc abc.c -c` can produce the file `abc.o` with same name ,and of course , same suffix `.o`. Even they have the same suffix `.o` , they are different. Do you means this ?

Comment: @guapi Just because you've named the file `.o` doesn't make it an object file. When you invoke `gcc` without the `-c` flag (and also without `-S` or `-E`), it will create an executable file. If you name your executable file `.o`, it will still be an executable file - just with a misleading extension.

Comment: @guapi `-c` produces object files. I don't know what else to tell you :-/ When you **don't** use the `-c` option, you get an executable file. When you **do** use the `-c` option, you get an object file. How you name that file does not matter.

Comment: @guapi File extension doesn't tell you the type of file. Not even on Windows. You can make an EXE file called "baking recipes.txt" and you can make a text file called "cool game.exe"